# Failing to load a pytorch ML model in a libtorch c++ project

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, libtorch

I am training a Semantic Segmentation model in a pytorch project and I want to load in a libtorch c++ project.

This is the pytorch code where I am trying to save the model (I also save it as an onnx and pth model):

```
trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)
date = datetime.now().strftime('%b%d_%H-%M-%S')
model_name = f'{config.train.epochs}ep_{date}.pth'
save_path = os.path.join("./trained_models/", model_name)
torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)

# Export the model to ONNX
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, config.train.res, config.train.res).to(model.device)
onnx_path = os.path.join("./trained_models/", f'{config.train.epochs}ep_{date}.onnx')
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, onnx_path)

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, dummy_input)
traced_script_module.save(f"./trained_models/{config.train.epochs}ep_{date}.pt")
```

And this is my c++ code where I try to load the pt model:

```
cout << torch::randn({ 2,2 }) << endl; // to check if torch works and it does
const std::string absolute_path = "C://model2.pt";

torch::jit::script::Module model;
try {
    model = torch::jit::load(absolute_path);
    cout << "Model loaded";
}
catch (const c10::Error& e) {
    std::cerr << "Error loading the model: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I get this error when i run the c++ code:

```
Error loading the model: [enforce fail at ..\..\caffe2\serialize\inline_container.cc:209] . file not found: model/version
```

The path to the pt model is good, I also tried to load the model from the folder where the source script is, I get the same error. I also tried backslashes instead of slashes in the path (even 1 or two of each).

When I try to load the same model in a python project it works, and I can access the model's layers.

I am working on Windows 10. In the pytorch project am I using torch 1.16+cu117 and my c++ project uses torch 1.6.0+cpu, but I read it should be possible to load the model even with different versions of torch.